# NRZ vs. Manchester pulse shaping filter (Modulator)

Tags: modulation

I'm trying to visualize the differences on the output waveform of a modulator when using NRZ or a Manchester pulse shaping filter. To keep it simple, let's think of a binary PAM signal with an input bit sequence 101011.

My thoughts are that with a Half Sine or a Raised Cosine pulse shaping filter, I will see the transitions between the 1's and 0's smooth out, but I'm struggling to think about the differences between the NRZ and the Manchester.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manchester coding effectively creates a bit sequence that is twice as long as the given bit sequence and then applies NRZ pulses to the resulting bit stream.
There are two types of Manchester coding. In one form, each $0$ in the original
sequence is replaced by $01$ and each $1$ by $10$ while the other form complements
these bit patterns.  Using the first form, 
$$101011 \to 10\,01\,10\,01\,10\,10$$ while the second form gives the complementary
bit sequence $01\,10\,01\,10\,0101$. If each data bit is of duration $T$, the NRZ
waveform with Half Sine pulses has sines of period $2T$ so that each bit
pulse has duration half a period. Thus, that leading $1$ gets
modulated to $\sin(\pi t/T)$ lasting from $t = 0$ till $t = T$.
With Manchester coding, each *channel* bit
(of duration $T/2$) gets a Half Sine of a sine of period $T$. Put another 
way,

- with plain NRZ, that first $1$ in your bit sequence will have
  pulse $\sin(\pi t/T)$ lasting from $t = 0$ to $t = T$. This is a positive
  going pulse rising from $0$ at $t=0$, peaking at $1$ at $t=T/2$, and
  falling to $0$ at $t = T$
- with Manchester coding, that data $1$ will become channel $10$ giving a positive pulse $\sin(2\pi t/T)$ from $0$ to $T/2$. The next channel bit
  $0$ has the *delayed* half-sine pulse $\sin(2\pi (t-T/2)/T$ from $t=T/2$
  to $t = T$, but with a *negative* amplitude (the *channel* bit 
  during this interval is $0$ instead of a $1$) which
  works out to be
  $$\begin{align*}
  -\sin(2\pi(t-T/2)/T) &= -\sin(2\pi t/T - \pi)\\
  &= -\sin(2\pi t/T)\cos(\pi) + \cos(2\pi t/T)\sin(\pi)\\
  &= \sin(2\pi t/T)
  \end{align*}$$
  lasting from $t = T/2$ to $t = T$. In short, *during the entire data
  bit interval* $[0,T]$ the signal can be expressed as $\sin(2\pi t/T)$
  and is *one* cycle of the sine wave of period T. If the *data*
  bit were a $0$ instead of a $1$, the channel bits would be $01$
  and we would get $-\sin(2\pi t/T)$ from $t=0$ to $t=T$. In short,
  Manchester coding with half-sine pulses
  effectively creates a *phase-modulated* signal
  from the data sequence with a carrier frequency of $1/T$ Hz and
  each data bit interval contains exactly one period of the sinusoid.
  If you look at the figure for Thomas's Manchester coding
  in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code),
  what we have is the $\pm$ rectangular pulses comprising each
  data bit interval, which look like a hard-limited sinusoid
  of period $T$, being replaced by the sinusoid.

> The OP says, "My thoughts are that with a Half Sine ....  pulse shaping 
>   filter, I will see the transitions between the 1's and 0's smooth out,..."
>   but this does not happen, there will be *abrupt* reversals of carrier
>   phase at those data bit boundaries where there is a transition
>   from $0$ to $1$ or from $1$ to $0$, pretty much as happens
>   in plain PSK.